# Understanding error with taking address of non-static member to form pointer to member function?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have an issue that I'm not sure how to get around.

I am using a library whose instances of the class are constructed by being passed references to a few functions.

```
void func_on_enter() {...}
void func() {...}
void func_on_exit(){...}

State state_a(&func_on_enter, &func, &func_on_exit);
```

I am writing a class that contains an instance of this class, and as such have attempted something like this:

```
class MyClass{
private:
  void func_on_enter() {...}
  void func() {...}
  void func_on_exit(){...}

  State _state_a;

public:
  MyClass() : _state_a(&func_on_enter, &func, &func_on_exit) {}
};
```

I get the error "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function. Say '&MyClass::_func_on_enter'" (and the same for the other two methods obviously). The compiler helpfully provides a solution, which I tried.

However the compiler then reminds me that there is no matching function for a call to `'State::State(void (MyClass::*)(), void (MyClass::*)(), (MyClass::*)())'` and that it has no known conversion from `'void (MyClass::*)()'` to `'void(*)()'`.

I tried reading up on similar questions about this error but can't seem to find a solution that I both understand and can help in this situation.

I considered trying to add an overload constructor to State, but this seems absurd to do on a class by class case, considering that I could be calling it from any other class.

I also thought for a while that I could just make the functions static (as they're the same for all instances of MyClass), but I quickly remembered that they would then be unable to use non-static member variables of MyClass.

Is there perhaps a way that I can provide a conversion or provide the pointers for the State constructor in another way?

I could really do with some help on this, as I'm quite stuck for ideas on how to move forward. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you in control of the `State` class?  If you are, switch from raw `void(*)()` pointers to `std::function<void()>` or template `State` on the type of the callbacks.  If you're not, what you want may be difficult to impossible.

Comment: A simple solution (which may not be applicable to you) is just to make `func` etc static.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I _can_ be in control of the State class - I've already forked the library it comes from to add more features. I suppose I need to remind myself of the inner workings of State to see if this would require me to rewrite (or template) the whole class or whether I can get away with overloading the constructor to accept `std::function<void()>`. I'm not very familiar with `std::function`, am I understanding correctly that they can be used similarly to pointers to indirectly call a function? If so, I can see this being the solution!

Comment: @john definitely could be helpful for others, but not in my case unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers to non-static member functions cannot be converted to plain function pointers.  A `void (MyClass::*)()` requires a `MyClass` object to operate on.  Raw pointers can't hold any sort of state though, so there's no way for a `void(*)()` to store the information about which `MyClass` object to operate on.

Luckily, the standard library has a class template designed for just this purpose: [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).  `std::function` is a more-or-less drop-in replacement for raw function pointers, but it can hold any type of callable object that's compatible with a given signature.  That means it can hold the state required to call back to a specific instance of a class:

```
class State {
private:
  std::function<void()> on_enter;
  std::function<void()> func;
  std::function<void()> on_exit;

public:
  State(std::function<void()> on_enter, std::function<void()> func, std::function<void()> on_exit)
    : on_enter{std::move(on_enter)},
      func{std::move(func)},
      on_exit{std::move(on_exit)}
  {}

  void do_something() {
    on_enter();
    // stuff
    func();
    // more stuff
    on_exit();
  }
};

class MyClass {
private:
  void func_on_enter() {}
  void func() {}
  void func_on_exit(){}

  State state_a;

public:
  MyClass()
    : state_a([this]() { func_on_enter(); },
              [this]() { func(); },
              [this]() { func_on_exit(); })
  {}
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e289c3bc9ab54561)

Here, instead of passing pointers to your member functions directly, I've wrapped them in lambdas that capture the `this` pointer of the object to be called back.  Now the `State` object is able to call those members, and they know which instance of `MyClass` to operate on.

Be careful about object lifetime though.  Since `state_a` holds pointers back to its `MyClass` instance, you'll need to ensure `MyClass`'s copy/move constructor and assignment operators do the right thing.  The default implementations provided by the compiler aren't sufficient.

Comment: I assume hat one must ensure that the lifetime of the given `State` instance does not exceed the lifetime of the `MyClass` instance it was initialized with. (In the given use case where the `State` is a member of the given `MyClass` this is guarenteed.)-- Very nice solution.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It's not guaranteed for copies of `MyClass` though. The `State` of the copy will refer to the source of the copy, whose lifetime may have ended.

Comment: A few questions @MilesBudnek:
1. Looking through your example, the only part I don't understand are the lambdas. How do they produce the `std::function<void()>` for the constructor of state_a? Or does the compiler implicitly convert them into `std::function<void()>`s?
2. If I want, for example, `state_a` to do nothing in place of `func()`, my previous State could be initiated with `NULL` wherever I didn't want a function call. Can I do this with this method?

Comment: @JRVeale 1. `std::function<void()>` is implicitly constructible from any callable object that takes no parameters and returns `void`, including lambdas. 2. `std::function` can hold no callable.  Use either the no-arg constructor or the one that accepts `nullptr`.  It's also contextually convertible to `bool`, so you can check if it holds a callable with something like `if (func) { func(); }` just like you would a raw function pointer.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I'm looking forward to implementing this now

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> void func_on_enter() {...}
> void func() {...}
> void func_on_exit(){...}
>
> State state_a(&func_on_enter, &func, &func_on_exit);
> ```

For this to work, the constructor of `State` must be accepting of function pointers of type `void(*)()`.

> ```
> _state_a(&MyClass::func_on_enter, &MyClass::func, &MyClass::func_on_exit)
> ```

For this to work, the constructor of `State` must be accepting of member function pointers of type `void (MyClass::*)()`. Member function pointers are not convertible to function pointers.

You could change the constructor of `State` to accept member function pointers of correct type.

Comment: This would work yes. As I'm likely to use State within other classes too I think using `std::function<void()>` in State (ss per @MilesBudnik 's suggestion) will be the best way forward to allow State to be called in _any_ class (and not just MyClass)

Comment: What's the difference between case 1 and case 2? Is the qualification in case 2 not redundant within MyClass?

Comment: I think this fundamentally disregards the design of `State`. It is supposed to work with a freestanding function. Introducing a dependency to e.g. `MyClass` (and how many others?) does not seem to be a good design decision, even if the OP can change `State`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider 1. The difference is that functions in case 1 are not non-static member functions. Functions in case 2 are non-static member functions. 2. The qualification is not redundant within `MyClass`. 3. The intended design of `State` has not been stated (until the comment to my answer which touches on a bit), except that OP wishes to pass non-static member functions into the constructor. It is sometimes OK to have dependencies between classes, and some classes can be intended to be used only with another class.

Comment: @eerorika Well, the relevant part of the design had been stated by showing the constructor call ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider As far as I understand, the first example shows how the class works, and second example shows how OP wants it to work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see now that the first quoted code was just the freestanding function example. Of course those cannot be qualified with a class name, and their type is indeed `void(*)()`.-- With respect to "the first example shows how the class works": it works that way because it was designed that way -- without a dependency to `MyClass`. I understand that the OP would find it convenient to pass member function pointers, but by doing that a dpendency is introduced which was apparently not planned in the original design. `State` is a generic name; it's not `MyClass::State`.