# Run-time exceptions when using std::functions. Why do they not point to valid code?

Tags: c++, std-function

I am working on putting together a library to enable easy implementation of Finite State Machines.

My library is based upon [arduino-fsm](https://github.com/jonblack/arduino-fsm), a library that achieves this by defining Fsm, State and Transition objects. arduino-fsm uses raw function pointers to set the functions that States and Transitions will call (functions that cover what to do when: entering a state, in a state, exiting a state, making a particular state transition). This library allows very intuitive state machine definition. However, it's use of raw function pointers means that an Fsm can't usefully be an instance variable of an object (raw function pointers can't point to non-static member functions, and static member functions can't access instance variables - making it impossible to have multiple different parent objects of the same class running different instances of the same Fsm.

My implementation replaces the use of raw function pointers with `std::function`s to define the States' and Transitions' functions in order to allow this (following answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513790/understanding-error-with-taking-address-of-non-static-member-to-form-pointer-to)).

I appear to be falling at the first hurdle, however. I'm having runtime exceptions that my stack backtrace shows are due to my `std::function`s not pointing to valid code ([reference](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-guides/fatal-errors.html#instrfetchprohibited)). I can't figure out why this is happening though.

The full code is [here](https://github.com/JRVeale/arduino-fsm/tree/use-std-functions/function-fsm-example), but I'll attempt to describe the code in short and the issue more clearly below.

---

The library defines the struct FunctionState and class FunctionFsm (FunctionFsm also defines the struct Transition).

FunctionState holds three `std::function`s called `on_enter`, `on_state` and `on_exit`. The functions they point to are called whenever the FunctionState is first entered, is active and is left, respectively.

FunctionFsm has functions to setup the fsm's transitions, to run the state machine, and to trigger transitions between states. It tracks the current state, and keeps a list of Transitions that define the state machine.

Transitions hold pointers to the state they move from and the state they move to, and 'event' integer (which allows particular Transitions to be triggered) and a std::function that points to a function to be called in that transition (after the first state's exit function is called).

In all, `std::function`s are used to tell each state what it's three functions are and to tell transitions what function it should use. (If no action is required for any particular state function or transition, the `std::function` may be set to `nullptr` - and the library will handle it appropriately.)

---

My simple example appears to fail in the fsm's setup, when it defines the first transition for the state machine.

Important bits from FunctionFsm in the library:

```
struct Transition {
  FunctionState* state_from;
  FunctionState* state_to;
  int event;
  std::function<void()> on_transition;
};

Transition create_transition(FunctionState* state_from,
                             FunctionState* state_to,
                             int event,
                             std::function<void()> on_transition){
  Transition t;
  t.state_from = state_from;
  t.state_to = state_to;
  t.event = event;
  t.on_transition = on_transition;

  return t;
}

void add_transition(FunctionState* state_from,
                    FunctionState* state_to,
                    int event,
                    std::function<void()> on_transition){
  if(state_from == NULL || state_to == NULL) return;

  Transition transition = FunctionFsm::create_transition(state_from,
                                                         state_to,
                                                         event,
                                                         on_transition);
  //stuff to keep track of number of transitions and add transition to the list
  //m_transitions is just a Transition*, manual memory management copied
  //like-for-like from arduino-fsm (which doesn't use stdlib features)
  m_transitions = (Transition*) realloc (m_transitions,
                                         (m_num_transitions + 1)
                                          * sizeof(Transition));
  m_transitions[m_num_transitions] = transition;
  m_num_transitions++;
}
```

Example:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';

//state functions
void a_on_enter(){ Serial.print("Entering a: "); }
void a_on(){ Serial.print(a); }
void a_on_exit(){ Serial.println(" - exitting a. "); }
void a_on_trans_b(){ Serial.println("Moving from a to b."); }

void b_on_enter(){ Serial.print("Entering b: "); }
void b_on(){ Serial.print(b); }
void b_on_exit(){ Serial.println(" - exitting b. "); }
void b_on_trans_a(){ Serial.println("Moving from b to a."); }

//states
FunctionState state_a(&a_on_enter, &a_on, &a_on_exit);
FunctionState state_b(&b_on_enter, &b_on, &b_on_exit);

//fsm    
FunctionFsm fsm(&state_a);  //state_a is initial state

//...

//add transitions
fsm.add_transition(&state_a, &state_b, TOGGLE_SWITCH, &a_on_trans_b);//crashes here
fsm.add_transition(&state_b, &state_a, TOGGLE_SWITCH, &b_on_trans_a);

//... code to run fsm, and trigger transitions as appropriate (hasn't had a chance to run yet)
```

I note that the crash is occurring on the first attempt to give a std::function a value, which shows that I'm handling it wrong somewhere in the library functions... But I really can't understand it. I don't think the function itself has been called anywhere, it's just that a std::function has assigned it?

The error itself is certainly [this](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-guides/fatal-errors.html#instrfetchprohibited) (as my microcontroller tells me it is) - I just can't figure out why...

I had wondered if I was asking too much of implicit conversion by providing functions that called for `std::function<void()>` with raw function pointers, but my testing shows no improvement if I explicitly create std::functions and then pass those instead.

I also worried about whether I'm passing my functions by reference or by value, but I don't think that makes a difference here either.

---

If anyone with more experience using `std::function` has any helpful suggestions, I'd be really grateful. I'm quite stuck and don't know how to move forward from here.

Comment: What's inside "//...stuff to keep track of number of transitions and add transition to the list"? Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: I had a quick look in your repo and spotted that `realloc` was hiding behind that comment. Don't use C's memory management in C++; it does not agree with object construction and destruction. Take your own word for it - "All this manual memory management seems silly" - and use `std::vector`. (I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure that it is.)

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo, I had the same thought when you asked me what was hidden. I've updated the question accordingly. I'll see if it works with `std::vector`s and post an answer if it does.

Comment: Can you run it with a debugger, so you could post a stacktrace and the thrown exception/ the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to @molbdnilo for reminding me to create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples and pointing out the likely cause, which is now confirmed.

It turns out the issue was with the use of a Transition pointer and `realloc` to keep a list of the fsm's transitions in a very C way rather than using a `std::vector<Transition>` (much more C++). I'd flagged this initially as poor practice, but hadn't considered the effect it may have had.

I haven't gone into understanding the full details of why using `realloc` has messed up my `std::function`s, but I can certainly see the vagueries of where this issue comes from.

Having updated the library to use a `std::vector` instead, everything works perfectly.

If anyone would like to provide a real explanation of the issue with using `realloc` in this case I'd be very interested to hear it! (I'd certainly mark it as an answer!)